# Checkout remote git branch if exists else clone master make new branch and push

Tags: ruby, git, shell, version-control, fastlane

Sorry for the verbose title.

In [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), using the programming language Ruby, I want to have this functionality:

```
if remote_branch_exist
  git_clone_remote_branch
else
  git_clone_master
  git_branch
  git_push_branch_to_master
end
```

**I have searched for a one liner git command that does that, but not succeeded. Is it possible?**

I have written this code that does exactly what I want. But it must surely be an unnecessary amount of code.

```
def git_clone_sdk_repo(path_repo: nil)
  some_branch = "some_branch"
  git_url = "git@github.com:MyComp/MyRepo.git"

  if check_if_remote_branch_exists(git_url: git_url, branch_name: some_branch)
    puts "remote branch exists"

    sh "git clone -b #{some_branch} #{git_url} #{path_repo}"
  else
    puts "no remote branch"

    sh "git clone #{git_url} #{path_repo}"
    pwd = Dir.pwd
    FileUtils.cd(path_repo)
    sh "git checkout -b #{some_branch}"
    sh "git push --set-upstream origin #{some_branch}"
    FileUtils.cd(pwd)
  end
end

def check_if_remote_branch_exists(git_url: nil, branch_name: nil)
  check_if_remote_branch_exists = "git ls-remote --heads #{git_url} #{branch_name} | wc -l | grep -o -q '1'"
  system(check_if_remote_branch_exists)
end
```

(The method `sh` in the code block above is used to call CLI commands. I think it is part of fastlane.)

Running this command:

```
git clone -b <some_branch> <git_url> <path_repo>
```

Results in:

```
fatal: Remote branch <some_branch> not found in upstream origin
```

If there is no branch in the remote with that name. So that is why I am first checking if there is a remote branch with such a name.

**What neat git command am I missing?**

Answer (score 3):

Let me re-express this task in Git terms, rather than as Ruby code.

You wish to:

1. Clone a repository from some URL.  We will then save that URL under the usual "remote" name, `origin`.
2. Given a branch name such as `foo`, check out that particular branch (so that the current commit is the tip commit of that branch).

   If the branch can be derived from a remote-tracking branch, as (e.g.) is usually true for `master` which usually derives from `origin/master`—you want Git to create this branch locally, with the corresponding remote-tracking branch set as its upstream, ready to do work on it.  Hence if branch `foo` exists in the Git repository on `origin` so that `origin/foo` will exist in the local repository, you want to create local branch `foo` with `origin/foo` as its upstream.

   If not, however—if there is no corresponding upstream name, so that at the moment, the branch is going to be a new branch—you want to create that new branch such that it points to the same commit that `origin/master` will point-to.  In this case, you then also want to immediately (or as quickly as possible) request that the Git on `origin` *also* create this branch-name, pointing to that very same commit, and on success, set `foo` to have `origin/foo` as its upstream.  Ideally, the end result of this process is that local branch `foo` exists and has `origin/foo` as its upstream.

You have observed that if `foo` exists on the remote, `git clone -b foo <url> <directory>` does the trick in one clean step (although as a side effect, the local clone will *not* have a `master` branch yet!).  If `foo` does *not* exist on the remote, though, the clone fails.

Unfortunately, there is no single Git command that can do all this.  Moreover, there is an *atomicity* issue here ("atomicity" having its usual meaning in database or parallel programming terms): the fact that `foo` does not exist during the cloning step does not mean that `foo` will not exist by the time you ask the upstream repository to create it.

The "best" answer to all of this depends on how much you care about this atomicity problem (solving it generally just moves atomicity issues to a later push step, since branch `foo` could be removed on the server by then, or have acquired extra commits, or been rewound and rewritten, or whatever).  But in the end you must use multiple Git commands.

#### Method 1

The sequence that uses the least *network traffic* is to clone without `-b`.  In this case, your clone will check out some branch all on its own—usually `master`, but the actual branch chosen will depend on what is in the `HEAD` entry for the Git at the URL that will be stored in the remote.  Your clone will then have the remote's URL saved as usual, under the name `origin` (or any `-o` argument you supply).

Now you can simply attempt to `git checkout foo`.  Either `foo` is already the current branch (because it was in `HEAD` on the remote), so that this is a successful no-op; or `foo` isn't the current branch.  If `foo` is not the current branch, thish will create `foo` as a local branch with `origin/foo` set as its upstream if and only if `origin/foo` exists.  This `origin/foo` will in turn exist if and only if a branch named `foo` existed on the remote *at the time you did the clone* (see "atomicity").

If the `git checkout` fails, you can assume that `origin/foo` does not exist.  (The only other possibility is that things are going very badly wrong, e.g., you have run out of disk space or the storage device is failing, or there are bugs in Git: in both cases all bets are off.)  You can at this point go down your "create `foo` pointing to the same commit as `origin/master` and use `git push -u` to ask to create it on `origin` too" path, and verify that this all works.  As usual with `git push`, you are now racing against anyone *else* creating `foo`.  Note also that there may not *be* an `origin/master` in your own repository, if there was no `master` on the other Git at the time you did the clone.

#### Method 2

You can use `git ls-remote` as you are doing now, which does one complete round-trip operation to the remote (currently via URL, since there is as yet no local clone, hence no remote named `origin` to *store* that URL) to determine the set of references it has.  If `foo` does not exist in that repository, you can ask that Git to create it.  You can do this a little bit differently, if you like, using a series of local Git operations in a new repository that, as yet, has nothing at all in it:

```
mkdir <directory>
cd <directory>
git init
git remote add origin <url>
```

At this point you can run `git ls-remote origin`, because now there *is* a remote named `origin`.  However, there are no local branches at all.  Now we run into the usual atomicity issues, and "what to do next" depends once again on how you wish to solve them.  But if I were not using method 1 or some slight variant of it, this is what I would do next:

```
# assumes $branch is set to "foo" as needed, and that
# function "die" prints an error message and exits with failure

git fetch origin  # bring over all commits and origin/* branches
if branchrev=$(git rev-parse -q --verify origin/$branch); then
    # origin/$branch exists, so we want to act like "git clone -b $branch"
    git checkout $branch ||
        die "unable to check out $branch, cannot proceed"
else
    # origin/$branch does not exist: ask to create it pointing to
    # origin/master
    rev=$(git rev-parse -q --verify origin/master) ||
        die "no origin/master exists, cannot proceed"
    git checkout -b $branch $rev ||
        die "failed to create $branch"
    git push -u origin "$branch:refs/heads/$branch" ||
        die "failed to create $branch on origin"
fi
```

The `git checkout -b` creates the branch in the local repository, and sets it as the current branch.  Since the initial commit ID is given by raw commit hash (due to `$rev` containing the result from `git rev-parse`), it will have no upstream.  You could instead use `git checkout -b $branch origin/master` but this will set the upstream for the new branch to `origin/master`, leaving a trap for the unwary if the `git push -u` fails for some reason (e.g., network failure).  You could use `git checkout --no-track -b $branch origin/master`, but given the test to make sure `origin/master` is a valid name, we might as well save the hash ID in `$rev` and use that.

This same bit of shell script—which you could rewrite in Ruby if you like—can be used after a regular old `git clone`, instead of using the somewhat obscure `git init; git remote add ...; git fetch` sequence that does everything `git clone` would do *except* for the initial `git checkout` of whichever branch the remote's `HEAD` indicates.

(In other words, in practice, I'd just run `git clone`—without the tricky `-b` part—first, then do everything in the shell script section above *except* the `git fetch` step, which is generally unnecessary right after the `clone` step.  If the clone will take a very long time, the extra `git fetch` might still be useful, since that will then shrink the atomicity race, at the cost of one more round-trip to the server at `origin`.  Nothing can completely close the race, though.)

Comment: That you for an amazingly thorough and pedagogical answer! For me atomicity is not an issue. But thanks for that.

Comment: So the answer is basically "not possible". If we - without considering atomicity - compare your shell script with my ruby code, does your solution have any advantage over mine?

Comment: @Sajjon: if you do one clone (or fetch-equivalent), then do the remaining operations using local information ("does origin/foo exist" etc), you will minimize the number of transfers over the network. That's about the only reason not to use `git ls-remote`, though.